# How to store a command's multi-line output to a batch variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am not a bro in batch scripts, but i can adapt.
I am trying to make a batch file that will check the firewall state, and toggle it(ON/OFF).
Note: [the output of the command contain ON or OFF in it's output alongside with other strings].

```
set "result=" netsh advfirewall show allprofiles state

IF not x%result:ON=%==x%result% (
    ::Disable Firewall
    NetSh Advfirewall set allprofiles state off
) ELSE (
    ::Enable Firewall
    NetSh Advfirewall set allprofiles state on
)
```

the problem as you see the result variable only contain the last line of the command output, so how to store the multi-line output of the command in a variable without having to store the command's output in a file as it seems redundant.

Comment: This is technically not a duplicate, because the OP does not require the use a [tag:for-loop] or need to `set` variables to the result of a command for this. Black Block, you should be able to do it with a single command line: `@NetSh AdvFirewall Show CurrentProfile State|Find "ON">NUL&&(NetSh AdvFirewall Set CurrentProfile State OFF)||NetSh AdvFirewall Set CurrentProfile State ON`.

Comment: (Note: the output of `netsh` is language dependent)

Comment: I'm aware of that myself @Stephan, but it's certainly worthy of mention for future readers. In this case, the OP used `ON` in their code, so I was confident in its use for my commented solution.

Comment: @Compo: yes, I'm sure, you are. My comment was intended for future searchers `:)`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it with a single command line without the need for variables or the use of a [for-loop](/questions/tagged/for-loop):

```bat
@NetSh AdvFirewall Show CurrentProfile State|Find "ON">NUL&&(NetSh AdvFirewall Set CurrentProfile State OFF)||NetSh AdvFirewall Set CurrentProfile State ON
```

For an extended [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) version, *also ensures that inbound and outbound rules are **set**. (Please note that these are examples only, not recommendations and have been provided to better show the layout of the original suggestion when split over multiple lines)*:

```bat
@Echo Off
NetSh AdvFirewall Show CurrentProfile State | Find "ON" >NUL && (
    NetSh Advfirewall Set CurrentProfile FirewallPolicy BlockInboundAlways,AllowOutbound
    NetSh AdvFirewall Set CurrentProfile State OFF
) || (
    NetSh AdvFirewall Set CurrentProfile State ON
    NetSh Advfirewall Set CurrentProfile FirewallPolicy AllowInbound,AllowOutbound
)
```

*Please note that these are language dependent, so may need adjustment if your system language is not English.*

*If you are not a member of the Administrators group, and UAC is enabled on your PC, run the script **as administrator**.*